# adding a script to the head of wordpress page with wp_register_script stopped working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a script that i use for a plugin in wordpress. It worked first but now it does not anymore. i've changed nothing, in the mean time i've only added the `wp_enqueue_script('aanmelden_evenement');` rule. Does anyone know what i'm doing wrong i'm out of ideas. also i've checked that `plugins_url('js/script.js', __FILE__ )` realy links to the right file and it does.

```
    function register_my_scripts(){
            wp_register_script('add_my_script', plugins_url('js/script.js', __FILE__ ));
            wp_enqueue_script('add_my_script');
    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_script','register_my_scripts');
```

Comment: It's [`add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', ... );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts), scriptS in plural.

Answer (score -2):

solved with

```
    add_action('wp_head', 'add_attr');
    function add_attr(){
            ?>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo plugins_url('js/aanmelden.js', __FILE__ );?>"></script>
            <?php
    }
```

Comment: Never add styles and scripts directly to `wp_head`